# SEO impact of identical reviews?

Tags: seo, local-seo

If a 5-star review is posted on both Google Local and Yelp (identical review text), does it affect the SEO in a negative way (duplicate content or anything else I may not be thinking of)? Or is it a positive, in the sense that there are now two positive reviews out there? To clarify, I am using Google and Yelp as examples, my question really applies to all review sites.

Comment: This really is not going to matter either way

Comment: See also: [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

Comment: In the case of an overzealous reviewer he/she may decide to copy and paste the same review on many sites, it's out of your control.

Comment: I would hope and suspect that Google would only reward for the first unique review and thereafter ignore any duplicates. Since its open for manipulate otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

The googlebot crawler is intelligent enough to identify situations where content may be duplicated for a reason, they already do this for product pages where the exact same text is present on a range of sites selling the same product. In addition the page taken as a whole will be different from the other customer ratings sites due to different customers adding ratings on different sites.

Comment: In the case of reviews, the full review often gets a page for itself.   If that is the case, Google may choose to index the full review on its own page on one of the two sites.